# ClassNotFoundException in spring project with maven

Tags: spring, tomcat, jar

I have created a spring project with maven and it works fine. I am trying to add a jar file to the project, eclipse does not give any errors but when i start the server and try to access to the page which uses a class from that jar file i get a classNotFound exception.

My steps are..

```
1 - I put the jar file in src->main->resources
2 - I added it to build path by right clicking and saying add to build path.
3 - I add the project to tomcat and start the server
```

The thing is i looked at the tomcat deployment directory and the .jar file appears in classes directory. When i take copy the file from classes to lib (which has libraries downloaded by maven) project works fine.

Comment: Jar file should be in the `lib` dir not in the `classes`.

Comment: I know but it should go to the lib directory automatically @StanislavL

Comment: You are using maven to manage your dependencies... Adding jars manually isn't what you should be doing, you should add the dependency to your `pom.xml`.